# Passing imageView to new activity imageView

Tags: android

Currently, my app allows the user to click on a "default avatar pic" and then select from a group of images. This image is then returned to the first activity via "startActivityForResult". My next task is to take the image that is now set in the first activity and send it to a third activity when the user presses the "submit button". Right now, I'm trying the below code, but it's not working as I don't know which image is going to be selected by the user until it's selected. Can anyone help me out here?

```
    findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.select_avatar);
            intent.putExtra("IMAGE", bitmap);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

             //second activity
             Bitmap bitmap = intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
             imageViewAvatar.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFinalAvatar);
             imageViewAvatar.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply use the ImageView Id as a integer or string value, then pass it. No need to use any bitmap. Bitmap takes too much memory.
Image should be work as a resource id if the image is selected from your resource folder. If your image comes from cloud, then definitely have a url as a string. So handle it as a **string as resource id/file path/url**.

```
int imageID = R.drawable.select_avatar;

findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putInt("image_id", imageID); // Integer Value
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

//second activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
int imageIdValue = intent.getIntExtra("image_id", 0);

imageViewAvatar.setImageResource(0);
imageViewAvatar.setImageResource(imageIdValue);
```

Comment: For a scalable solution check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47272329/7355128 hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you need to receive an **ImageView** on another activity, you might face scalability problems in the **future** with your app.

If you have your avatar image on the first activity selected, that drawable selection can be saved in a local storage like [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), then in your **second activity** and any other activity you have on the future you can retrieve that value from **SharedPreferences** as-well, for example:

**Store** your Drawable **idName**: (You **DON'T** want to store the **int id** because that id changes if you add more drawables and it can **break your app** in the future)

```
int[] drawablesArray = {R.id.monkey, R.id.balloon};
int id = drawablesArray[imageSelectedIndex];
String idName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("avatarPicture",idName);
editor.apply();
```

**Retrieve** your Drawable **idName** on the second **Activity**:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this);
int avatarPicture = preferences.getString("avatarPicture", "");
if(!avatarPicture.isEmpty())
{
    imageView2ndActivity.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier(idName, "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you miss the knowledge of how getting results from another Activity, please see the [official](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) documentation.
The second Activity that have to receive the information, needs to be called by a method called onActivityResult(example from the link)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

Usually in real life scenarios developers use  [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) (steep learning curve this last one)